# Need a description of the map $i:\mathbb{C}P^2\vee\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2\times \mathbb{C}P^2$ on $2$nd Cohomology level

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $i:\mathbb{C}P^2\vee\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2\times \mathbb{C}P^2$ be the inclusion map. I want to know what is $i^*$ on $2$nd Cohomology level. Seems it should be an isomorphism between $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2\vee\mathbb{C}P^2) $ and $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2\times\mathbb{C}P^2) $. But can't find a rigorous proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the cofibration seuence $\mathbb{C}P^2\vee\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2\times \mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2\wedge \mathbb{C}P^2$. Note that $\mathbb{C}P^2\wedge \mathbb{C}P^2$ is 3-connected.

Comment: @Tyrone I am actually new to Cohomology theory and don't know cofibration. Can you please explain it in some other way?

Comment: I could, but rather than my ramblings you might prefer Hatcher's treatment in *Algebraic Topology* $\S$ 2.1 pg. 113, 'Exact Sequences and Excision'.

Comment: I think you claimed in your last post that you know cellular homology? Simply put the product  structure on $\mathbb{C}P^2\times\mathbb{C}P^2$ and you'll get the answer.

Comment: @Tyrone  Thanks .. will try this out. So, is my intuition correct about $i^*$ being an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{C}P^2$ has a cell-structure $e^0\cup e^2\cup e^4$, and you see from this that the 2-skeletons of $\mathbb{C}P^2\vee \mathbb{C}P^2$ and $\mathbb{C}P^2\vee \mathbb{C}P^2$ are identical. (In fact the 3-skeletons are the same).